# MySQL replication changes not being sent

Tags: mysql, replication

I've setup mysql replication only for a specific database on the master.

If I connect to the master and don't specify a database (e.g. in the connection string or with the `'use database'` command) the statement is not sent to the slave. Is this a bug?? Why does this happen?

## Example 1

with no db specified up till now: **won't replicate**

```
insert into exampledb.mytable values(1,2,3);
```

## Example 2

**replicates**

```
use exampeldb;
insert into mytable values(1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bug. This behavior is [defined in the MySql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db):

> The main reason for this “check just
>   the default database” behavior is that
>   it is difficult from the statement
>   alone to know whether it should be
>   replicated (for example, if you are
>   using multiple-table DELETE or
>   multiple-table UPDATE statements that
>   go across multiple databases). It is
>   also faster to check only the default
>   database rather than all databases if
>   there is no need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was causing alot of heartburn and somehow we missed this in the docs. I don't really like how MySQL handles this but I guess they did explain it.